# scrapy response selector to lxml

Tags: scrapy, lxml

Indeed, I read this question [converting scrapy to lxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29657575/converting-scrapy-to-lxml) in detail.
But in my project, dozens of crawlers use scrapy selector. It'll cost us much time to convert scrapy to lxml line by line. So I try to write some compatible code to migrate crawlers.

```py
    class ElemList(list):
        def __init__(self, elem_list=[]):
            super(ElemList, self).__init__(elem_list)
    
        def xpath(self, xpath_str=""):
            res = []
            for elem in self:
                try:
                    e = elem.xpath(xpath_str)
                except Exception as e:
                    continue
                if isinstance(e, str) or isinstance(e, unicode):
                    res.append(e)
                else:
                    res.extend(e)
            return ElemList(res)
    
        def extract(self):
            res = []
            for elem in self:
                if isinstance(elem, str):
                    res.append(elem)
            return res
```

In response class, add some init call.

```py
    from lxml import etree
    
    class Response(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.elem_list = ElemList(etree.HTML(self.html))
        def xpath(self, xpath):
            return self.elem_list.xpath(xpath)
```

With this class, then I can call response object like this:

```py
    resp.xpath('//h2[@class="user-card-name"]/text()').extract()
    resp.xpath('//h2[@class="user-card-name"]').xpath('*[@class="top-badge"]/a/@href').extract()
```

It works. But new problem comes, how can I migrate response.css like this?

```py
    baseInfo_div = response.css(".vcard")[0]
    baseInfo_div.css(".vcard-fullname")
    baseInfo_div.css(".vcard-username")
    baseInfo_div.css('li[itemprop="worksFor"]')
    baseInfo_div.css('li[itemprop="homeLocation"]')
```

Comment: a bit off topic, but why do you want lxml instead of scrapy Selectors ?

Comment: We decide not to use scrapy for crawlers and need migrate our crawlers.

Comment: you can use [parsel](https://github.com/scrapy/parsel) which is scrapy's selectors without scrapy itself. So you would only need to change the imports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to implement your logic using [`cssselect()`](http://lxml.de/cssselect.html#the-cssselect-method) method from [`lxml.cssselect`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cssselect), which enables you to query from `lxml`'s `Element` object using CSS selector expression. Or you can translate CSS selector into XPath selector using `GenericTranslator.css_to_xpath()` :

```py
from lxml import html
h = html.fromstring('''<div id="outer">
<div id="inner" class="content body">
       text
</div></div>''')
content = h.cssselect('div.content')[0]
content.text    
# output :
# '\n       text\n'

from cssselect import GenericTranslator
GenericTranslator().css_to_xpath('div.content')    
# output :
# u"descendant-or-self::div[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' content ')]"
```